# Why is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, exact-duplicates

A question I asked:

[A problem with 26 distinct positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619088/a-problem-with-26-distinct-positive-integers?noredirect=1#comment1370054_619088)

was characterised as a duplicate of:

[Creating a sequence that does not have an increasing or a decreasing sequence of length 3 from a set with 5 elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316006/creating-a-sequence-that-does-not-have-an-increasing-or-a-decreasing-sequence-of)

Can anybody explain to me why?

Comment: It appears that your question is the $n=5$ case of the result mentioned in [Ross Millikan's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/316019).

Comment: The first question is about a partially ordered set (natural numbers under divisibility) and the second about permutations of an ordered set.  It is not at all obvious to me that they are equivalent.

Comment: I think some folks go dup hunting find something remotely similar in the title or the body... even if it is a bit of a stretch and flag it. But that's just my perception.. its probably in error.

Answer (score 2):

The question has since been re-opened by the votes of five community members.